# rsyslog x509/certvalid requiring permitted peer

Tags: linux, ssl, tcp, x509, rsyslog

**EDIT:** After battling with this issue, it seems to be actually be many different issues all glomming together under some general issues regarding Rsyslog.
 So a better "TL;DR" summary of the problem: "Many vague/conflated problems arise from using Rsyslog with TLS. How can I make it work?"  My answer summary is below.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I have been struggling with getting `rsyslog` to output TLS from a client to a server, specifically while using the "fingerprint" or "certvalid" modes.

I have multiple machines, one of which is the server to receive the syslog data over TCP/TLS on port 11514. The rest of the machines are clients sending the TCP/TLS. All have certs signed with the same Certificate Authority (whose key is stored elsewhere). These machines are NOT attached directly to public IP addresses and do NOT have DNS entries.

Depending on what version was available for which platform (ranging from 7.6 to 8.4), different machines would exhibit different behavior even when trying to share the similar configs among them all. The `gtls` module proved a constant, fickle hassle as it would error out in odd, different ways for each machine. It might error out depending on the order of configuration lines or if I used Rainer-script style or used Legacy style or used the machine's hostname in the cert's CN or didn't, etc, etc, etc.

Although, the exact specifics of what each mode does is not well documented (after looking at sparse explanations like this: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ns_gtls.html), I am choosing not to use "x509/name" because it doesn't seem to serve any purpose for me. Unless I am mistaken "x509/name" matches the CN of the machine cert installed on the server to whatever is in `PermittedPeers`. However, contrary to all the examples, my machines do not have DNS entries, hence the cert's CN is entirely arbitrary. (However, for this last machine's config, gtls continued to fail until I made the CN match my hostname. Coincidence or what's going on...?)

I just want the signing certs on each machine to be verified against each other (since they are the same signing cert and the reason I'm using "x509/certvalid"). I am not opposed to getting verification by certificate fingerprint, also, if I could ever get it to work (or find documentation on exactly how).

On my last machine, I am getting an error saying that the remote host's name (the rsyslog server) does not match the permitted peers. *Why* it even *needs* that for **"x509/certvalid"**, I do not know. I then tried adding the server cert's fingerprint to permitted peers (in my best guesses for the expected format, with or without colons, ":", or "SHA1:"). All failed the same way and I cannot figure out why.

It may be worth noting, this setup on THIS machine actually worked before I had to change out all the certs on all the machines (using the same method that I always use: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/tls_cert_machine.html). Then a series of ridiculous failures followed: failed to load gtls, failed to use the Legacy options with the new style `action(type="omfwd"...)`, etc,etc, with `service rsyslog restart`, `systemctl restart rsyslog` and `kill -HUP $(pidof rsyslog)` all hanging or leaving it in odd different states. After a final config polish and a full machine restart (boo, not sure if this is a systemd problem or something else...), I was left with a permitted peer error generated from this client...

The client machine's rsyslog version:

```
rsyslogd 8.4.2, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
    memory allocator:                       system default
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:                           Yes
    Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

Snippet of the client machine's `rsyslog.conf`:

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /folder/ca_cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /folder/ca_cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /folder/client1_cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /folder/client1_key.pem
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/certvalid
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
...
ruleset(name="forwardtls") {
    action(type="omfwd" target="192.168.1.1" port="11514" protocol="tcp"
      ResendLastMSGOnReconnect="on" StreamDriverMode="1"   
      StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/certvalid" 
      StreamDriverPermittedPeers="SHA1:AA:BB:CC:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88")
}
*.* call forwardtls
```

Client machine's error:

```
Feb  7 23:59:35 client2 rsyslogd-2087: authentication not supported by  gtls netstream driver in the configured authentication mode - ignored [try http://www.rsyslog .com/e/2087 ]
Feb  7 23:59:35 client2 rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 1' suspended, next retry is Wed Feb 10 00:00:05 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog .com/e/2007 ]
Feb 8 00:00:01 client2 rsyslogd-2088: error: peer name not authorized -  not permitted to talk to it. Names: CN: server1;  [try http://www.rsyslog .com/e/2088 ]
```

Snippet of server machine's rsyslog.conf:

```
$ModLoad imtcp
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /folder/ca_cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /folder/server1_cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /folder/server1_key.pem
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/certvalid
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1
$InputTCPServerRun 11514
```

Answer (score 6):

As anyone can guess, this "problem" is about much more than a "valid peer" error. The practical solution, unfortunately, will be very specific to distro, distro version, rsyslog version and so many other inconsistent things that no quick answer will suffice.

After much struggling and much staring at this question without an answer (and in place of an overly general "meta" answer), here is what I have found...

If you plan on using Rsyslog with TLS, you should first take a few things into account: how different or old are your systems and how much patience do you have for failure. If you need it to run immediately, be ready to change some plans.

First of all, most distributions are the first problem. If you want to use RELP with Rsyslog's TLS, you need at least Rsyslog version 7.5. Some distributions (especially ones based on RedHat) only have version 7.4. Even older Debian-based LTS distros will not have a sufficiently recent version for full support of Rainer scripts. Want to know the specific version you need for everything? Start digging through the changelogs or other frustrated forum posts.

Don't expect the documentation to tell you everything you need. Although generally very good, the online documentation is sometimes amiss. (For example, "omrelp" module shows the exact format for TLS fingerprints, but plain "tcp" with TLS does not; "omrelp" has examples all in Rainer script format but plain "tcp" with TLS does not)

Expect troubleshooting to be painful. Rsyslog unfortunately incorporates GnuTLS into everything but also punts log messages to GnuTLS. Depending on where it is in the process of creating a TCP connection, authenticating, determining proper crypto, etc, it will generate very opaque GnuTLS error codes (which often only mislead you from the REAL problem when you look them up or naively dig for answers in GnuTLS source code) and an online reference URL (which may or may not have a short, vague reference to anything helpful).

Sometimes rsyslog will tell you that the connection is not from an authorized peer. Sometimes it won't. I have had many "GnuTLS error code -110" with reasons ranging from zombie TCP sockets to mis-typing a filename in the config. The codes are nearly useless. Even worse, some client installs would say nothing about the error because it would silently not log anything past the rsyslog service initiation (and would also seemingly wreck other services, presumably ones that touched the same unix sockets, though I am not entirely sure).

Old distributions will cause you pain. Different distributions using different versions of Rsyslog will also cause very different results. For example, on a recent Debian build (with Systemd) running "service rsyslog stop" will stop it as normal but "systemctl stop rsyslog" will "stop" the *service* but an rsyslogd process might still run in the background. Woops? If you try to restart the rsyslog process, many times the TCP session will not close (*FIN*) between server and client, causing the new process to fail.

Don't expect any of this to get caught by the "-N" option, though (since it only consistently works for syntax).

Best advice for tweaking configs: figure it out yourself by triple-checking your configs (including all filenames and permissions for any stated filenames), stop the service, kill the process, wait a few minutes for any TCP sessions to timeout, try again. Otherwise, you might be running a new service atop an old process with an old config and an invalid socket.

If you want to install from the rsyslog repo ("adiscon"), to get the very latest of relp, Rainer scripts, etc, it may work very well or you may still have the above problems compounded with other issues. On Ubuntu installs, with rsyslog, rsyslog-relp and rsyslog-gnutls split into separate packages, someone decided to overlap core files, effectively breaking the installation. (Why wasn't this fixed when it was noticed months ago??)

On some installations, everything will work fine the first time. On some installations, you will bang your head on the keyboard.

Alternatives:

-- Use RELP or normal UDP syslog combined with **stunnel** or **sslwrap** or similar. Preferably, use RELP pointed to your local TLS tunnel port. This way, if your tunnel goes down (seperately from Rsyslog) it can queue logs until fixed (quickly- before that queue fills).

-- Use syslog-ng. If you experience enough pain at the beginning, why not try a complete alternative...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working configuration for an environnment which don't use DNS entries :

Server and client have the same rsyslog version :

```
rsyslogd 8.16.0, compiled with:
PLATFORM:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):      
FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
memory allocator:           system default
Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
uuid support:               Yes
Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

(I use also x509/certvalid instead of x509/name)

Important :

- use IP adress instead of name for the certificate step
- check if syslog account can read the three files ca-pm,client/server-cert.pm and client_server-key.pm (i had to chmod 444 on client-key.pm)

**On the SERVER :**

apt-get install rsyslog-gnutls

/etc/rsyslog/conf (I've just put the beginning... - but order is important !):

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################


$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability


################
#####TLS#######
###############

# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /home/server/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /home/server/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /home/server/server-key.pem


$ModLoad imtcp


$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/certvalid
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer=["CLIENT_IP"]
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1
$InputTCPServerRun 10514
```

service rsyslog force-reload

**On the CLIENT :**

(leave default settings from /etc/rsyslog.conf) :

- apt-get install rsyslog-gnutls

touch /etc/rsyslog.d/lts.conf :

```
# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /home/client/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /home/client/client-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /home/client/client-key.pem

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# gtls Network Stream Driver
#  x509/name - certificate validation and subject name authentication
#  http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ns_gtls.html
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/certvalid
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer=["COLLLECTOR_IP"]
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1


*.*                                              @@COLLLECTOR_IP:10514
```

service rsyslog force-reload

Comment: I can't believe this got an answer after so long!  I was doing my permitted peer with peer cert hashes `"SHA1:123abc..."` and that worked fine. IP didn't always work in my networking scenario (NAT/Forwarding). I think `service rsyslog force-reload` and `service rsyslog restart` were not resetting the socket (at least) so that was my main problem. All I know is that any time I have to touch CentOS 6, I will now assume the fetal position.